# What does "sin" mean in sin_addr, sin_family etc,?

Tags: sockets, unix, network-programming

I am new to UNIX socket programming and I am wondering what is "sin" in sin_addr, sin_family etc, short for? And what does "in" mean or is short for in struct socketaddr_in?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is shorthand for the name of the struct (`sockaddr_in`) that the member-variables are a part of.

Similarly, the [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/sockaddr-2) inside `sockaddr_in6` all start with the prefix `sin6_`, and the variables inside `sockaddr` start with the prefix `sa_`, and so on.

`in` is presumably shorthand for "internet".

Comment: This convention generally holds up for other `sockaddr` types as well, like `sun_` for `sockaddr_un` members, `sll_` for `sockaddr_ll` members, `ss_` for `sockaddr_storage` members, etc (it is not used in Microsoft's `SOCKADDR_BTH`, though).