# In struct "sockaddr_in", what do the member prefixes "sin" represent?

Tags: c, sockets, posix, sockaddr

In the sockaddr_in struct, each member features a "sin" prefix. What do these prefixes represent?

[image]

Comment: Probably **s**ockaddr_**in**

Comment: @JohnnyMopp I was curious if that was the case. It just seems unnecessary though and I don't see this naming technique used in many other structs.

Comment: The struct is used as an input initializer when binding a socket....  For example:`address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, 
                                 sizeof(address))<0)`

Comment: @Izzo Back in olden times, before Intellisense, people use Hungarian notation and other systems to give hints about the code in the names. So if you saw `s.sin_family`, you wouldn't need to lookup what `s` is - you'd see it was a `sockaddr_in`.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that's very interesting and makes sense.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp if you submit this response as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715651/5451030

Take a look at that answer, it seems to be a shorten version of `sockaddr_in`